# Values from a JSON response in ajax returning as undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm having some problems when trying to retrieve values from a JSON response sent via the `$.post()` method in jQuery. Here is the script:

```
var clickedName = $('#customerId').val();

$.post("/customer-search", { name: clickedName }).done( function(response) {
    var results = $.parseJSON(response);    
    console.log(results);

    $('#account-name').html(results.firstname + ' ' + results.lastname);
    $('#email').html(results.email);
    $('#telephone').html(results.telephone);
    if (results.fax) {
        $('#fax').html(results.fax);
    } else {
        $('#fax').html('n/a');
    }
    $('#personal').fadeIn();
    return false;
});
```

Just to explain, I'm using twitter typeahead in a Symfony2 project, and basically this script will fire when a name is clicked (selected) from the list after typing. The customer-search URL runs a search of the database as follows:

```
$q = $request->request->get('name');
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$customer = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Oc73Customer')->findLikeName($q);
$addresses = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Oc73Address')->findByCustomerId($customer[0]['customerId']);

$results = array();
$results['customer'] = $customer;
$results['addresses'] = $addresses;

return new Response(json_encode($results));
```

Which will successfully return a Json encoded response, and the value of 'response' which is printed in the console (as per the jquery above) is:

```
{
    "customer": [{
        "firstname": "Mike",
        "lastname": "Emerson",
        "email": "xxxx@xxxx.co.uk",
        "telephone": "01234 5678910",
        "fax": null,
        "password": "8e1f951c310af4c20e2cd6b68dee506ac685d7ae",
        "salt": "e2b9e6ced",
        "cart": null,
        "wishlist": null,
        "newsletter": 0,
        "addressId": 84,
        "customerGroupId": 1,
        "ip": null,
        "status": 1,
        "approved": 1,
        "token": null,
        "dateAdded": {
            "date": "2016-02-16 12:59:28.000000",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
        },
        "availCredit": null,
        "customerId": 75
    }],
    "addresses": [{}]
}
```

I am trying to retrieve the customer details by using the method I always use, so to get the firstname, I use `results.firstname` where results is a parsed JSON string, as written in my jQuery response.

However, all I get from `results.firstname` is `undefined`, even when it clearly is defined. So, basically, I'm wondering what I am doing wrong?

Hope someone can shed some light on my problem.

Comment: Because there is no `results.firstname` property - theres a `customer` property - which contains an array of objects - which has a `firstname` property: `results.customer[0].firstname` should work.

Comment: because results is an array of objects, you should either loop the customers (by looping results) or just access them like this: `results.customer[0].firstname;`. Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/eLrqzzbf/ (nice try anyway, and well exposed question)

Comment: If you don't already use a JSON parsing tool (like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)), I would suggest adding one to your arsenal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The properties you're trying to access are objects in the `customer` array, not on the parent object itself. Assuming that the response only ever contains one customer object then you can use `result.customer[0]`, like this:

```
$.post("/customer-search", { name: clickedName }).done(function(response) {
    var results = $.parseJSON(response);
    var customer = response.customer[0];

    $('#account-name').html(customer.firstname + ' ' + customer.lastname);
    $('#email').html(customer.email);
    $('#telephone').html(customer.telephone);
    $('#fax').html(customer.fax ? customer.fax : 'n/a');
    $('#personal').fadeIn();
});
```

If it's possible that multiple `customer` objects will be returned in the array the you would need to amend your code to loop through those objects and build the HTML to display them all - without using `id` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access it like "results.customer[0].firstname"

```
var cus = 
    {
    "customer": [{
        "firstname": "Mike",
        "lastname": "Emerson",
        "email": "xxxx@xxxx.co.uk",
        "telephone": "01234 5678910",
        "fax": null,
        "password": "8e1f951c310af4c20e2cd6b68dee506ac685d7ae",
        "salt": "e2b9e6ced",
        "cart": null,
        "wishlist": null,
        "newsletter": 0,
        "addressId": 84,
        "customerGroupId": 1,
        "ip": null,
        "status": 1,
        "approved": 1,
        "token": null,
        "dateAdded": {
            "date": "2016-02-16 12:59:28.000000",
            "timezone_type": 3,
            "timezone": "Europe/Berlin"
        },
        "availCredit": null,
        "customerId": 75
    }],
    "addresses": [{}]
}
    alert(cus.customer[0].firstname);
```